# How to load entity in EF Core with the 'AsNoTracking' method in combination with explicitly loading of related entities

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I am currently using this approach for loading entity and their related entities with `AsNoTracking`:

```cs
await DbContext.Clients
                .Include(x => x.AllowedGrantTypes)
                .Include(x => x.RedirectUris)
                .Include(x => x.PostLogoutRedirectUris)
                .Include(x => x.AllowedScopes)
                .Include(x => x.ClientSecrets)
                .Include(x => x.Claims)
                .Include(x => x.IdentityProviderRestrictions)
                .Include(x => x.AllowedCorsOrigins)
                .Include(x => x.Properties)
                .Where(x => x.Id == clientId)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Code detail on Github: [link](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin/blob/master/src/Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.EntityFramework/Repositories/ClientRepository.cs#L33-L45)

This works, but this query is very slow, after migration to EF Core 3.0.

I have found that is possible to fix this performance issue via loading of related entites explicitly like this:

```cs
IQueryable<Entities.Client> baseQuery = Context.Clients
                .Where(x => x.Id == clientId)
                .Take(1);

            var client = await baseQuery.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (client == null) return null;

            await baseQuery.Include(x => x.AllowedCorsOrigins).SelectMany(c => c.AllowedCorsOrigins).LoadAsync();
            await baseQuery.Include(x => x.AllowedGrantTypes).SelectMany(c => c.AllowedGrantTypes).LoadAsync();
            await baseQuery.Include(x => x.AllowedScopes).SelectMany(c => c.AllowedScopes).LoadAsync();
            await baseQuery.Include(x => x.Claims).SelectMany(c => c.Claims).LoadAsync();
            await baseQuery.Include(x => x.ClientSecrets).SelectMany(c => c.ClientSecrets).LoadAsync();
            await baseQuery.Include(x => x.IdentityProviderRestrictions).SelectMany(c => c.IdentityProviderRestrictions).LoadAsync();
            await baseQuery.Include(x => x.PostLogoutRedirectUris).SelectMany(c => c.PostLogoutRedirectUris).LoadAsync();
            await baseQuery.Include(x => x.Properties).SelectMany(c => c.Properties).LoadAsync();
            await baseQuery.Include(x => x.RedirectUris).SelectMany(c => c.RedirectUris).LoadAsync();
```

Code detail on Github: [link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.Storage/src/Stores/ClientStore.cs#L54-L71)

Unfortunately, I have tried rewriting this sample with the `AsNoTracking` method, but it is not working - related entities are not loaded.

How can I rewrite my original query via a faster performance with the AsNoTracking approach?

I need to do not track the client entity for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EF Core documentation says that v3 now generates joins and this query is a victim of *cartesian explosion problem* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Documentation says also that in previous versions EF was generating separate query for each include. So in my opinion fine solution would be

```
var baseEntity = await DbContext.Clients.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == clientId);
baseEntity.AllowedGrantTypes = await DbContext.ClientCorsOrigins.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ClientId == clientID).ToListAsync();
baseEntity.RedirectUris = await DbContext.ClientRedirectUris.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ClientId == clientID).ToListAsync();
...
...
```

And so on until you will get all related resources you need. It will mimic previous behaviour. 
If you really need to use navigation properties then you cannot use `.AsNoTracking()` unfortunately. If my idea looks too naive - only other way I can think of is to detach entities from tracking context after using navigation properties.

So after implementing code from second link you would need to go through entites in your object and mark them as detached
`DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;`

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't and you shouldn't.
Firstly it looks dangerous what you are doing in the original call, what is the purpose?
Never the less, includes are slow and require joins. But I remember that AsNoTracking always should go first directly after the entity call. And then the includes for example. Same goes for Where case, put that directly after AsNoTracking to see if it makes a difference.

But read this thoroughly [Related Data Docs, EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)
Espcially the part about **Explicit loading**:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blog = context.Blogs
        .Single(b => b.BlogId == 1);

    context.Entry(blog)
        .Collection(b => b.Posts)
        .Load();

    context.Entry(blog)
        .Reference(b => b.Owner)
        .Load();
}
```

And related entities  *This allows you to do things such as running an aggregate operator over the related entities without loading them into memory.*

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blog = context.Blogs
        .Single(b => b.BlogId == 1);

    var postCount = context.Entry(blog)
        .Collection(b => b.Posts)
        .Query()
        .Count();
}
```